# Regex to change only number inside a div

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I have this regex for now

```
/<div[^>]*>|(\d{1,9}\.\d{2})/
```

which detect the opening of a `<div>` and group the number in a currency format inside it.

If I have a string like this

```
<div class="foo">Hello world 4546.00 and 6596.45 bla bla bla</div>
```

I would like to only replace the numbers inside it with a `preg_replace`

As you can see in the example below, I don't want the number outside of the div to be selected, only ones inside.

https://regex101.com/r/AZd896/1/

Comment: @ctwheels we I need to summon him because it will be helpful to finish my client's task from hell ;)

Comment: What you're looking to do is outside the scope of the capabilities for regular expressions.  Regexes can find patterns in code, but they can't get semantic meaning.  See http://htmlparsing.com/regexes for examples of why you don't want to try to parse HTML with regexes.

Comment: @AndyLester Lord Satan who goes by the name of `ctwheels` gave me a good regex which helped me do my `preg_replace`. And it's working like a charm https://regex101.com/r/AZd896/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

I'm not sure why you got downvoted so quickly, but I can only assume it's because of this question's topic and its relationship with [regex match open tags except xhtml self contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

By no means is this the best answer, but, in the scope of your question, it does solve your issue.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/AZd896/2)

```
(?:<div[^>]*>|\G(?!\A))(?:(?!</div>).)*?\K\d{1,9}\.\d{2}
```

If the `<div>` tag might span multiple lines, you can add the `s` modifier to allow `.` to match newline characters [as seen here](https://regex101.com/r/AZd896/3).

---

### Results

#### Input

```
dasdfasdf 355.56 asdfasd
<div class="sdaf">sdfsad 36546545643.00 asdfa sdf sadfasdf 544.45 sadfs</div>
dasdfasdf 355.56 asdfasd
```

#### Output

```
dasdfasdf 355.56 asdfasd
<div class="sdaf">sdfsad 36 asdfa sdf sadfasdf  sadfs</div>
dasdfasdf 355.56 asdfasd
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?:<div[^>]*>|\G(?!\A))` Match either of the following

  - `<div[^>]*>` Match the following

    - `<div` Match this literally
    - `[^>]*` Match any number of any character not present in the set (anything except `>`)
    - `>` Match this literally
  - `\G(?!\A)` Assert position at the end of the previous match
- `(?:(?!</div>).)*?` [Tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) matching any character any number of times, but as few as possible, and ensuring not to match `</div>`
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match.
- `\d{1,9}\.\d{2}` Match 1-9 digits, followed by a literal dot `.`, followed by exactly 2 digits

Comment: Please note that this approach will break if the <div> is not on the same line as the text.

Comment: @AndyLester [the `s` modifier can be used](https://regex101.com/r/AZd896/3). I added a note to my answer including this logic.

Answer (score 1):

While Parsing HTML with regex sounds like fun, please use a proper XML parser instead. You can use the following `DOMDocument` code to achieve, this functionality:

```
<?php

$html = 'dasdfasdf 355.56 asdfasd
<div class="sdaf">sdfsad 36546545643.00 asdfa sdf sadfasdf 544.45 sadfs</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($divs as $div)
{
    $innerText = $div->nodeValue;
    $div->nodeValue = preg_replace('(\d{1,9}\.\d{2})', 'whatever', $innerText);
}

$html = $doc->saveHTML();

var_dump($html);
```

Now, with this you only have to parse with REGEX the inner string instead of the `<div>` itself.